# How create modal window with Twig template and Twitter-Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, fosuserbundle

I use Symfony and boostrap to customize the style of my website.
I have a twig file : register_content.html.twig which contains a register form.

In my index.html.twig I want to have something like that :

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Je m'inscris !</a>
```

To display the content of the register form in a modal window, but it doesn't work.

I try to use the twitter-bootstrap documentation here : 
http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/javascript#modals

But I can't find a way to apply it easily for twig in symfony...

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is totally unrelated to symfony or twig. You are missing **data-attributes** for the modal to work!

You can do it the following ways:

1. Integrate the register form inside your `index.html` in a modal box and following the bootstrap example for a static modal box:

   ```html
   <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">I register !</button>

   <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
       <!-- register form here -->
   </div>
   ```
2. You could also load the content for the registration form through ajax. In this case, see the remote option for modals:

   ```html
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" data-target="#myModal">click me</a>

   <div id="myModal"></div>
   ```

   Just make sure to not send any layout when an ajax request is performed against the url, because otherwise you'll have a complete html page inside your div, which is neither valid (html-page inside html-page) nor a good idea.