# Bootstrap Modal doesn't inject content in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've an problem with modal box in Bootstrap3.

My code:

```
<a data-remote="{{ path('popup_pages', {'page': 'cgu'}) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Try</a></p>

<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content"> 

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link is OK, I can retrieve the content without modal.

Now, I want to inject in the modal-content my page at the link `{{ path('popup_pages', {'page': 'cgu'}) }}` (don't take care about syntaxe, I use Twig, but an good link is generate).

For the moment, when I click on the link, it remove my html and only display a mailto (weird...) without changing page.

If I remove the data-remote and hard code content in modal-content, this work.

Any idea?

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you read this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867580/how-create-modal-window-with-twig-template-and-twitter-bootstrap Looks to me you are doing exactly what's described there. If so then your problem is in some code you are not showing us.

Comment: I haden't see this post, but it's the same, I don't see was is wrong in my case...

Comment: Then please do some basic debugging, maybe create a fiddle so we can test your code in context. Right now the question lacks any information we could use to help you.